# ProxySQL with multiple reader_hostgroups

Tags: mysql, proxysql

I have a ProxySQL instance that is currently configured with one master and two replication slaves for basic read/write query splitting.

However, I would like to configure different sets of slaves for different users. Specifically, I want to set it up so that e.g. db_user_1 uses hostgroup 1 and 2, while db_user_2 uses hostgroup 1 and 3, where, hostgroup 1 represents the master, and hostgroup 2 and 3 are two different sets of replication slaves.

Is it possible to achieve this level of user-specific slave configuration within a single ProxySQL instance?